# Simple Automapper Example

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-entities, automapper

I am having a hard time to understand how to map certain objects. Please answer some questions about this simple example.

*Example code*

```
class User
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
}

class Group
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private List<User> users;
}

[DataContract]
public class UserDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name{ get; set; }      
}

[DataContract]
public class GroupDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }      
}
```

*The mappers*

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDto, User>();

Mapper.CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<GroupDto, Group>();
```

When mapping `Group` to `GroupDto`, do you have to map `User` to `UserDto` internally because the `List<User>` in `Group` consist of unmapped `Users`? If so how do you do this? My guess is

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>()
    .ForMember(g => g.id, opt => opt.Ignore());
    .ForMember(g => g.name, opt => opt.Ignore());
    .ForMember(g => g.Users, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => Mapper.Map<Group, UserDto>(u)))
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Why doesn't your GroupDTO contain UserDTO's? If it did, no more configuration other than `CreateMap` would be needed for AutoMapper to work.

Comment: Here is  simple article i have written on Automapper using C# http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/986460/What-is-Automapper

Comment: Read this article: http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/12/csharp-object-to-object-mapping-automapper.html

Comment: It would help if there was an updated copy of the article posted above. I don't believe it's valid in AutoMapper 5.x.

Answer (score 31):

1- Change the GroupDto to be like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class GroupDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<UserDTO> Users { get; set; }      
}
```

2- Create your mappings :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDto, User>(); // Only if you convert back from dto to entity

Mapper.CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<GroupDto, Group>(); // Only if you convert back from dto to entity
```

3- that's all, because auto mapper will automatically map the `List<User>` to `List<UserDto>` (since they have same name, and there is already a mapping from user to UserDto)

4- When you want to map you call :

```
Mapper.Map<GroupDto>(groupEntity);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: "since they have same name," -- does type important also? If one object is list and another one is ICollection, does it require a member mapping?

Comment: I would like to see an updated example for AutoMapper 5. I don't think most of this is valid anymore.

Answer (score 6):

As @stuartd said, if you change :

```
[DataContract]
public class GroupDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }      
}
```

for :

```
[DataContract]
public class GroupDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<UserDTO> Users { get; set; }      
}
```

you just need :

> Mapper.CreateMap()

Otherwise, change

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>()
    .ForMember(g => g.id, opt => opt.Ignore());
    .ForMember(g => g.name, opt => opt.Ignore());
    .ForMember(g => g.Users, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => Mapper.Map<Group, UserDto>(u)))
```

for something like :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Group, GroupDto>()
    .ForMember(g => g.id, opt => opt.Ignore());
    .ForMember(g => g.name, opt => opt.Ignore());
    .ForMember(g => g.Users, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => Mapper.Map<List<User>>(g.Users)))
```

This has not been tested, but the idea is here....