# cannot convert from Models.<entityviewmodel> to Models.<entity>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Database first approach and I want to use my own validation I tried to modify generated model, and it works:

But, if I need to update model from DB, of course my validation code overwrites Entity Data Model and attributes disappear. How can I overcome the situation with my own validation?

So what I end up doing that I have created a within same namespace and I have named `ClientViewModel` and in this class I have all my custom validation and its works until when I try to save and I get the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(myapp.Models.Client)'
>   has some invalid arguments

here is my controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Create(ClientViewModel client)
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        try
         {
            using (var context = new db_entities())
            {
               //more code...        
               db.Clients.Add(client); //<<<ERROR
               db.SaveChagnes();
             }
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need use automapper. 

view this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635534/simple-automapper-example

Comment: You need to map you view model to the data model and save the data model

Comment: i have the same prop what `Client` and `ClientViewModel` has

Comment: you may know that, but the compiler doesn't.

Comment: Make no difference, they are different types

Comment: @StephenMuecke: can you please elaborate little bit more on types, I even have the same namespace. an example would be better

Comment: @AbuHamzah, You have a data model which is typeof `Client` (i.e `public class Client { ..}`, but your view model is type of `ClientViewModel` (i.e. `public class ClientViewModel { ..}`. You db context expects typeof `Client` but you are passing it an instance of `typeof `ClientViewModel` which causes the error

Comment: what is the best way to deal just map the view model?, please reply as answer so i can accept that and it would be good if you provide with an example

Comment: There are a number of options, including getting the original data model then updating its properties from the view model, creating a new data model e.g. `var c = client.Select(x => new Client() { ID = x.ID, Name = x,Name ...});` and adding it to the context, or using tools such as [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end-up using `AutoMapper` and its a tedious situation without using the `AutoMapper` It not only reduces the effort, but also limits the execution time that has been taken by such a large number of lines to execute.

Here is my updated code:

```
  Client clientModel = Mapper.Map<ClientViewModel, Client>(client);
  db.Clients.Add(clientModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert the viewmodel into a model class that EF tracks. Assuming both your ViewModel and Model have 3 properties x, y and z, you can see something like this:

```
public Client ConvertViewModelToModel(ClientViewModel vm)
    {
        return new Client ()
        {
            x = vm.x,
            y = vm.y,
            z = vm.z
        };
    }
```

And then call this to convert the viewmodel:

```
var clientModel = ConvertViewModelToModel(vm);
```

You can then go about adding this clientModel to the db.Clients collection and go about saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the database to be created properly. if not then try :

```
>Enable-migrations
>add-migration model
>update-database
```

Maybe solved by this. I tried it which solved mine.