# Convert collections of database entities to collections of view models

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, swagger, entity-framework-core

I am working on a .NET Core Web API

So far I used to return anonymous types in my controllers but now I want to start using the full power of swagger with auto documentation of the return types.

Which lead me to start using view models.

But I am struggling with converting between the auto-generated database model classes
and the auto-generated swagger view model classes.

It works for a single instance (see `GetPerson` method in the controller below) but fails when I want to return lists.

So my questions:

1. How do I cast/convert collections/lists of objects between view models and database models
2. Is the code in the controller correct? Are there easier/shorter/better ways to do the conversion? (I read about using the `implicit operator`)

Error message I get:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

It gives me an `InvalidCastException` if I cast them explicitly like

```
List result = (List)_dbContext.Person....
```

there seems to be a problem with generics in the display of stackoverflow
Assume I used the generic lists with giving a type PersonView

My code looks like:

Database models

```
    public partial class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public int? MainAdressId { get; set; }

        public virtual Adress MainAdress { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Adress
    {
        public Adress()
        {
            Person = new HashSet();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public int CityPostalCode { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }
        public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public string FloorNumber { get; set; }
        public string DoorNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection Person { get; set; }
    }
```

View models

```
    public class City
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int PostalCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Street
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public string FloorNumber { get; set; }
        public string DoorNumber { get; set; }

    }

    public class AdressView
    {
        public Street Street { get; set; }
        public City City { get; set; }

    }

    public class PersonView
    {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        public AdressView Adress { get; set; }

    }
```

The controller class which is working for a single instance but not for lists

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen.Annotations;
using PersonExample.ModelsPersonDB;
using PersonExample.ModelsViewPerson;

namespace PersonExample.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PersonViewTestController : Controller
    {

        private readonly PersonDBContext _dbContext;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public PersonViewTestController(PersonDBContext dbContext, ILogger logger)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _logger = logger;
            _logger.LogDebug("{0} > new instance created", GetType().Name);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetPerson")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(PersonView), 200)]
        [SwaggerOperation("GetPerson")]
        public virtual IActionResult GetPerson([FromRoute]int id)
        {

            PersonView result = _dbContext.Person
                                    .Include(p => p.MainAdress)
                                    .Where(p => p.Id == id)
                                    .Select(p => new PersonView()
                                        {
                                           FirstName = p.Firstname,
                                           Lastname = p.Lastname,
                                           Adress = (p.MainAdress == null) ? null :
                                               new AdressView()
                                               {
                                                   Street = new Street()
                                                   {
                                                       Name = p.MainAdress.StreetName,
                                                       HouseNumber = p.MainAdress.HouseNumber,
                                                       FloorNumber = p.MainAdress.FloorNumber,
                                                       DoorNumber = p.MainAdress.DoorNumber
                                                   },
                                                   City = new City()
                                                   {
                                                       Name = p.MainAdress.CityName,
                                                       PostalCode = p.MainAdress.CityPostalCode
                                                   }
                                               }
                                        }
                                    )
                                    .FirstOrDefault();

            return new ObjectResult(result);
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetPersonList")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(List), 200)]
        [SwaggerOperation("GetPersonList")]
        public virtual IActionResult GetPersonList()
        {

            List result = _dbContext.Person
                                    .Include(p => p.MainAdress)
                                    .Select(p => new PersonView()
                                    {
                                        FirstName = p.Firstname,
                                        Lastname = p.Lastname,
                                        Adress = (p.MainAdress == null) ? null :
                                               new AdressView()
                                               {
                                                   Street = new Street()
                                                   {
                                                       Name = p.MainAdress.StreetName,
                                                       HouseNumber = p.MainAdress.HouseNumber,
                                                       FloorNumber = p.MainAdress.FloorNumber,
                                                       DoorNumber = p.MainAdress.DoorNumber
                                                   },
                                                   City = new City()
                                                   {
                                                       Name = p.MainAdress.CityName,
                                                       PostalCode = p.MainAdress.CityPostalCode
                                                   }
                                               }
                                    }
                                    );

            return new ObjectResult(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use AutoMapper https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

here some examples: [Simple Automapper Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635534/simple-automapper-example)

example with EF core and ASP.NET WebApi: https://github.com/chsakell/aspnet5-angular2-typescript

Comment: is using a dedicated mapping library the only way?

Answer (score 1):

I missed the `.ToList()` at the end of the query.

The full controller know looks like:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetPersonList")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(List), 200)]
[SwaggerOperation("GetPersonList")]
public virtual IActionResult GetPersonList()
{

    List result = _dbContext.Person
                            .Include(p => p.MainAdress)
                            .Select(p => new PersonView()
                            {
                                FirstName = p.Firstname,
                                Lastname = p.Lastname,
                                Adress = (p.MainAdress == null) ? null :
                                       new AdressView()
                                       {
                                           Street = new Street()
                                           {
                                               Name = p.MainAdress.StreetName,
                                               HouseNumber = p.MainAdress.HouseNumber,
                                               FloorNumber = p.MainAdress.FloorNumber,
                                               DoorNumber = p.MainAdress.DoorNumber
                                           },
                                           City = new City()
                                            {
                                                Name = p.MainAdress.CityName,
                                                PostalCode = p.MainAdress.CityPostalCode
                                            }
                                        }
                             }
                             ).ToList(); //missed that line

    return new ObjectResult(result);
}
```