# After mapping DTO using AutoMapper, the Id field becomes 0

Tags: c#, automapper

Please find code below:

```
public class CustomerDto
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

// ...

var customers = _context.Customers.ToList();
var cusDtos= Mapper.Map<List<Customer>,List<CustomerDto>>(customers);
return cusDtos;
```

All objects in `cusDtos` have value for all property except `Id`, `Id` is 0 for all objects. customers contains value for `Id`, but after mapping the `Id` becomes 0.
Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544782/2932057) may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change this code

```
var cusDtos= Mapper.Map<List<Customer>,List<CustomerDto>>(customers);
```

change with this

```
var cusDtos= Mapper.Map<List<CustomerDto>>(customers);
```

and find the automapper profile. And change this

```
 CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
         .ForMember(m => m.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

to this

```
 CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper configuration:

```
CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();
```

Your code:

```
var customers = _context.Customers.ToList();
var cusDtos = customers.Select(x => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CustomerDto>(x)).ToList();
return cusDtos;
```