# Recursively merging two objects of the same type

Tags: c#, recursion, merge

I'm looking to combine two objects of the same type in C# so that I can come up with a third instance of the same type, but with combined or overridden properties, according to a convention.

Short of writing a bunch of very gross manual code that requires me to handle each property individually, are there any well known techniques or utility libraries that might be able to make this less of a manual effort?

Comment: Please give an example of what you want.

Comment: If I had that, then I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: By example I mean concrete use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Is recursion really necessary in order to map two objects of the same type? Could you 
not use [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/) .

As the objects are of the same type mapping their property is straight forward. Moreover you have control over what member to include or whether to override or combine source and destination etc.

This is a nice SO post to check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635534/simple-automapper-example)

Comment: It's necessary in so far that some properties may be lists that need to be combined, and other properties may be lists that need to be overwritten.