# Shorthand for selecting from a database entity into a view model with same property names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 project I have a model generated by Entity Framework for an entity in my database:

```
public partial class EmailType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm working with this entity in a view I use a view model, which is basically identical to the base entity class, without the Last Modified fields, since I believe that's best practice.

What I want to know is whether there's a quick way of selecting records from the database into my view model. If I just used the base entity class it'd be as simple as:

```
List<EmailType> emailTypes = db.EmailType.ToList();
```

But because I'm using a view model I have to write this:

```
IList<EmailTypeViewModel> emailTypes = db.EmailType
.Select(e => new EmailTypeViewModel
{
    ID = e.ID,
    Description = e.Description,
    Enabled = e.Enabled,
    Subject = e.Subject,
    Body = e.Body
})
.ToList();
```

And this is just a simple example. When I'm working with view models that have associated child view models it gets very long-winded. Is there a shorthand way of selecting from the database into a view model using LINQ that doesn't require me to write out every property every time?

Comment: you can use automapper to do this conversion, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635534/simple-automapper-example, you can also use a custom extension method for your project.

Comment: There is no specific code in asp.net for this, but if you prefer a external package, you can use a package like automapper

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out automapper. Can't believe there isn't a native API for this, it's such a common use case.